# NSPredicate that uses @max with an other condition in a fetch request

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have a CoreData entity `Song` that has date property `pushDate` and a boolean property `isPublic`.

I need to fetch the latest public song.

To get the latest, I can use -

```
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"pushDate==max(pushDate)"];
```

But when I try -

```
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"pushDate==max(pushDate) AND isPublic == YES"];
```

I don't get any result (I am 100% sure that I have songs with public == YES).

Can I use this predicate ? If no why / what is the correct way to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to do `isPublic == YES` without the `max(pushData)` condition?

Comment: As @pbasdf noted, if the latest song is not public, this predicate will return no results.  Unless I'm reading it wrong, to fulfill this predicate, a Song must have the max pushDate (be the latest song) and also have isPublic set to YES.  The predicate does not look for the latest public song, only the latest song if it happens to be public.  Please excuse the repetition, but it seems like a basic point is being missed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try do fetch all objects are `public` first.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isPublic == YES"];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
```

Use a sort descriptor to sort `pushDate`:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDesc = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"pushDate" ascending:NO];
[request setSortDescriptors:@[sortDesc]];
```

Set the limit of the request to one:

```
[request setFetchLimit:1];
```

Comment: @shannoga, are you able to find a solution for your issue yet?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that `max(pushDate)` is evaluated across ALL Songs, not just the public ones.  If the most recent Song (ie the one that meets the first clause, `pushDate == max(pushDate)`) is NOT public, then it will fail the second clause (`isPublic == YES`).

If you want "the most recent public song", then you must filter down to the public songs, before finding the most recent.

To do that, I would use a predicate that fetches only public songs:

```
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isPublic == YES"];
```

And also specify a sortDescriptor that sorts the results in order of descending `pushDate`:

```
request.sortDescriptors = [[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"pushDate" ascending:NO]];
```

The first item in the results will be the song you want.  To avoid fetching all the rows, use:

```
request.fetchLimit = 1;
```

before performing the fetch.

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

```
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"pushDate==max(pushDate)" AND "isPublic == YES"];
```

I think it may be a case of missing quote marks.

Aside Note: That is one of the reasons I prefer to use compound predicates... They're easier to read in my opinion.